# Values in if statement are not being returned, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I am evaluating confidence interval for accuracy on a data set, and I calculate 95% or 99% confidence interval, however values corresponding to the lower interval and upper interval are not being returned from the function, please guide me as to what exactly I am doing wrong:

```
function [Accuracy,lowerInterval,upperInterval] = ConstructInterval(Ypredict, Ytest, confLevel)
n = size(Ypredict,1);
correct = Ypredict == Ytest;
Accuracy = mean(correct);
confLevel = floor(confLevel*100);
if(confLevel == 99)
    lowerInterval = Accuracy - 2.576*sqrt(Accuracy*(1-Accuracy)/n);
    upperInterval = Accuracy + 2.576*sqrt(Accuracy*(1-Accuracy)/n);
end
if(confLevel == 95)
    lowerInterval = Accuracy - 1.96*sqrt(Accuracy*(1-Accuracy)/n);
    upperInterval = Accuracy + 1.96*sqrt(Accuracy*(1-Accuracy)/n);
end
Accuracy = 100*Accuracy;
lowerInterval = lowerInterval*100;
upperInterval = upperInterval*100;
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: I tried debugging and the values for lowerInterval and upperInterval are being set, but they are not being returned, I cannot understand why.

Comment: I tried that as well but the function is not returning the value for the two variables, I have changed my code so as to work around if there was any problem with the if statement but it doesn't seems to work, and the function is going into the if block but the values are not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when i was calling the functions, i was only saving the values as:

```
f = ConstructInterval(y(testInstanceLabel == 1),pred_linear, 0.99)
```

instead of

```
[f,g,h] = ConstructInterval(y(testInstanceLabel == 1),pred_linear, 0.99)
```

rookie mistake.